# ExtJS - Add a tooltip to the header of a Panel

Tags: extjs, header, panel

I'm developing an application that use Ext.panel.Panel control. This panel has a body and a header. What I need to do is to add a tooltip (just text) to the header of the panel (onlye the header not the body)

I was trying with this:

```
    listeners: {
    render: function () {
        this.getEl().dom.title = 'my custom tool tip';
    }
},
```

but it works only for the body, not the header. Do you have any idea how to do it? I'm using Ext 4.2.1

Edit:

This is how I'm trying to show the tooltip

```
Ext.define('XXX.XXX.XXX.MyCustomPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

setMyTitle: function() {
    var ds = this.getDataSource();

    try {
        this.setTitle(ds.getCustomTitle());
        // Add tooltip where tooltip = ds.getCustomTitle();

    } catch (e) {

    }
},
```

Thanks,
Angelo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure attributes for header's underlying HTML element with the [autoEl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Header-cfg-autoEl) config in the panel's [header](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-header) config:

```
header: {
    autoEl: {
        title: 'This is a tooltip'
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use [QuickTips](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tip.QuickTipManager):

```
header: {
    autoEl: {
        'data-qtip': 'This is a tooltip'
    }
}
```

Also see this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1op).

**EDIT:**
Applying the tooltip after the panel was already rendered (adjusted to your code):

```
setMyTitle: function() {
    var ds = this.getDataSource(),
        title = ds.getCustomTitle();

    try {
        this.setTitle(title);
        // again, obviously just one out of the two attributes
        this.getHeader().getEl().set({
            'title': title,
            'data-qtip': title
        });
    } catch (e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: is not working. Maybe I did the question wrong but when I do Ext.Panel.panel.SetTitle, a title is showed (I can guess that is a header), so what I need is to show a tooltip when to pass the mouse over that title.

Comment: I've added a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1op), as you can see there it is working. Can you provide more code in your question to actually reproduce your problem?

Comment: ok I've added more information of how I'm trying to show the tooltip

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `Ext.tip.ToolTip` and assign it to your header:

```
var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: 'clearButton',
    html: 'Press this button to clear the form'
});
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.tip.ToolTip